# Using JSON to retrieve different id from data base

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an HTML img tag with an empty src and I use JSON and jquery to retrieve the src of the img from the database when the user hovers over a parent span  that contain the img tag. The problem is when I retrieve the src with JSON everything is fine and the image src is retrieved but I a loop set for this span in the very same page, so when the first image is already retrieved it's src is applied for the other looped span images. It is like retrieving the same id of the first image for the other different looped images that suppose to have different id for different content image contents.

here's is my code  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#key').hover(function(){
        var id=$('#im').attr('value');
        $.post('getjson.php',{id:id},function(data){
            $('img').attr('src',data.user_img);
        },'json');
    }); 
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
  {loop="data"} <span class="foo" id="key">{$value.user_key}</span> <span class="foo">
  <img alt="ther is an image here" src="" value="{$value.id}" id="im"/></span>
```

Comment: Post your html too.

Comment: post ALL html body

Comment: maybe its becasue you use $('img') selector which selects all the images in the page and applies the src attribute to it... post your html to look into it more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have duplicated IDs on your page. So, `$('#key')` will always return the first `DIV` with the id `key`, the same for `$('#im')`. Instead this `$('img')` will select all images on your page. Here is a demo to illustrate the problem:

```js
console.log("$('#key') count:"+$('#key').length);
console.log("$('#img') count:"+$('#key').length);
console.log("$('img') count:"+$('img').length);

$('#key').hover(function(){
  console.log("ID hovered: "+$('#im').attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="key"> Div 1
  <img src="" id="im" value="1"  />
</div>
<div id="key"> Div 2
  <img src="" id="im" value="2"  />
</div>
<div id="key"> Div 3
  <img src="" id="im" value="3"  />
</div>
<div id="key"> Div 4
  <img src="" id="im" value="4"  />
</div>
```

To solve that you need to use another selector, for example, use a class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-selector').hover(function(){
        //This will select all images inside 'this' (hovered .key)
        var img = $('img', this);
        $.post('getjson.php',{id : img.attr('value')},function(data){
            img.attr('src',data.user_img);
        },'json');
    }); 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  {loop="data"} <div class="my-selector"> <!-- add parent div -->
      <span class="foo" id="key">{$value.user_key}</span> 
      <span class="foo">
         <img alt="ther is an image here" src="" value="{$value.id}" id="im"/>
      </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried changing the id to class is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, use a different selector than the ID. You can change to `<span class="foo key">` if you don't use the `#key` selector somewhere else.

Comment: Or you can use `.foo` instead !

Comment: it works and everything is fine but one more thing I should hover the first span <span class="foo" id="key">{$value.user_key}</span>  the image should appear but that does not happen I must include the class in the parent span which is <span class="foo my-selector"> <!-- add class my-selector --> in order to for the image to appear due to inheratance

Comment: I want to achieve this when I hover over the first span  <span class="foo" id="key">{$value.user_key}</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing
`$('img').attr('src',data.user_img);`
to
`$("img[value='"+ id +"']").attr('src',data.user_img);`

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are setting the source to all images on the page.

$('img') should be replaced with $('#key')

in your case the code should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#key').hover(function(){
        var img = this;
        var id=$('#im').attr('value');
        $.post('getjson.php',{id:id},function(data){
            $(img).attr('src',data.user_img);
        },'json');
    }); 
});
```